# Going from the apocalypse to X-years post-apocalypse in a logical and realistic way

Tags: technology, post-apocalypse

I'm currently developing a post-apocalypse story idea, where a virus caused the death of a lot of humans and in advanced phases spread to animals and made them insane (don't want to have zombies nor zombie animals, only mutant animals that attacks humans on sight) but the majority of those animals are afraid of lights so the threat is high during the night only.

Now we jump to the story, it's X years since the apocalypse (determining the X is part of the question), in a city that restored a little of the old life. They surrounded the city with walls and guards and started farming and manufacturing for a group of nobles ruling the city (This is not dystopia).

Now to the question. I have the two edges of the timeline, the start of the apocalypse, and the actual time when the story is happening. Only I'm struggling to find what happened during this period and how long it was. I think the only way to answer these two questions is to know what technologies are still preserved and to what level.

**So here is the actual state of the technology in my settings** (I used a template from an answer I found [here](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/a/106626/15795))

**Medicine**

Basic medicine and easy drugs.

**Agriculture**

Farming & Fishing are there but I'm still undecided if it's with machines or by hand;
Animals can still be tamed but at higher risks (if a cow is infected it'll surely attack at night).

**Weapons & Self-Defense**

Poor people use medieval weapons but nobles and city guards have access to fire guns (either because the nobles hold the knowledge or they lack materials)

**Manufacturing**

The industry is there (or at least I need it to be) so in my setting, there is a large part of the population of the city working in large scale factories owned by the nobles. It’s basically metal work but I’m unsure what those factories can “realistically” be producing. It can be producing radios for communications or fluorescent light tubes to keep animals away or other electronic parts. I’m also thinking of the walls made of steel and concrete, farming tools and weapons but there is the struggle to make things realistic, you need to know a thing to know the others.

**High-Tech**

None. At least in the city, maybe in some parts of the country or the world, there is mecha and robots but I don’t think it really matters.

**Motorized transport**

Same for weapons, there are cars and trucks but only for nobles and necessary work (patrol, food transportation…) and there are bikes for lesser rich people (and horses for the rest). So there are working oil wells and refineries but at a lesser scale which makes the access to cars and fuel very expensive.

**Electricity**

Hardly maintained but is used for priorities like factories, food storage, defenses, and of course for nobles' houses. Important streets and places are lit by fire during the night.

There is I think the global situation of how I imagine my setting, so how can I go from the apocalypse to this in a logical and realistic way?

*(Excuse my English, not my first language)*

Comment: The time period and the events within are driven by your plot and narrative requirements.  Human politics are rarely logical and realistic. Your story must merely *seem plausible enough* to keep the suspension of disbelief. Example: A reader will forgive many silly and unrealistic things if they can identify with the protagonist's character or situation.

Comment: Not quite an answer, but you should check out [Microscope](http://www.lamemage.com/microscope/), which is a pen and paper game designed around co-operatively building fictional histories. The framework it uses can easily be used by one person to fill in the blanks while Worldbuilding.

Comment: @JoeBloggs It seems interesting, definitely gonna check this out. Thank you!

Comment: @user535733 Can I know please why you guys closed this ? I don’t see any story driven thing in there you closed it just because you don’t like how its formulated or what? If the question was can this technologies still be there it would have been left open! It suck!

Comment: @AimanVargas we closed it because you seemed to be asking us to plot out your world's history for you "*how can I go from A to B in a logical and realistic way?*" which is something we definitely won't do. That's an important part of being a creator. If we misunderstood what you are asking for, then you are welcome to edit the question to improve understanding.